# Given a linear transformation and basis, verify $ [T]_{\beta}^{\alpha}[v]_{\alpha} = T[(v)]_{\beta}$ . (More details in description)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $T : R^3 -> R^2 $ be the linear transformation defined by
$T(x,y,z) = (3x +2y -4z, x-5y +3z)$, and let $\alpha$ = {(1,1,1), (1,1,0), (1,0,0)} and $\beta$ = {(1,3),(2,5)}. 
$Verify$ $ [T]_{\beta}^{\alpha}[v]_{\alpha} =  T[(v)]_{\beta}$

This is a sub question of my assignment and I did not understand the verification part. How do you define $[v]_{\alpha}$ and $ T[(v)]_{\beta}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[v]_\alpha$ denotes the column vector consisting of scalars of $v$ w.r.t the ordered basis $\alpha$ and similar for other.

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me a small example if v = (1,2,0)? Would [v]α =1*(1,1,1)+2*(1,1,0) + 0*(1,0,0)?

Comment: No, if $v=(1,2,0)=0(1,1,1)+2(1,1,0)-1(1,0,0) \text{then}
  [v]_{\alpha}=(0,2,-1)^t$

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!